# How do I see what logical volumes are on a physical volume?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a volume group composed of dissimilar drives - an HDD and an SSD.  I'd like certain LVs to live on the SSD.  I can suggest this to `lvcreate` when creating new LVs, and I can move things around with `pvmove`, but how do I see what the current state is?

Comment: Does it make sense then to put the different drives into the same VG?

Answer (score 10):

This is surprisingly hard to find in the documentation, but the [manpage for lvdisplay](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvdisplay) gives some good information.  First, `lvdisplay -m` will show you the relevant information for a particular logical volume:

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/lvm/base
LV Name                base
VG Name                lvm
LV UUID                9bFriv-5DA2-3NSA-FeSO-6hKj-Un3j-74rzWQ
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ,
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                25.00 GiB
Current LE             6400
Segments               4
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           254:7

--- Segments ---
Logical extent 0 to 2971:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda11
    Physical extents    0 to 2971

Logical extent 2972 to 5530:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda10
    Physical extents    0 to 2558

Logical extent 5531 to 6398:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda9
    Physical extents    1024 to 1891

Logical extent 6399 to 6399:
    Type                linear
    Physical volume     /dev/sda7
    Physical extents    2429 to 2429
```

In many cases what you want to know is the reverse: what LV's are on a PV.  For that, `pvs --segments -o+lv_name,seg_start_pe,segtype`:

```
knuth ~ # pvs --segments -o+lv_name,seg_start_pe,segtype
PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  Start SSize LV                                         Start Type
/dev/sda10 lvm    lvm2 a--  10.00g     0      0  2559 base                                        2972 linear
/dev/sda11 lvm    lvm2 a--  11.61g     0      0  2972 base                                           0 linear
/dev/sda5         lvm2 a--  10.00g 10.00g     0     0                                                0 free
/dev/sda6         lvm2 a--  10.00g 10.00g     0     0                                                0 free
/dev/sda7  lvm    lvm2 a--  10.00g  2.99g     0   769 buildslave                                  2303 linear
```